# Highlighting multiple matches in a given string

Tags: php, regex

I have this function in PHP which I use to highlight search terms in the given string:

```
 function highlight_match($h, $text_to_search){ 
    foreach($h as $pattern){
        $text_to_search = preg_replace("/($pattern)/i", "<span class=\"highlight_match\">$1</span>", $text_to_search);
    }
    return $text_to_search;
 }
```

Using the function like this works fine:

```
 $h = array(
     'peter',
     'bell'
 );
 $text_to_search = 'peter pan likes tinker bell'
 echo highlight_match($h, $text_to_search);
 // results: <span class="highlight_match">peter</span> pan likes tinker <span class="highlight_match">bell</span>
```

The problem occurs when the search term contains part of what was just replaced(added) in a previous iteration,  like this example:

```
 $h = array(
     'pan',
     'bell'
 );
 $text_to_search = 'peter pan likes tinker bell'
 echo highlight_match($h, $text_to_search);
 // results: peter <s<span class="highlight_match">pan</span> class="highlight_match">pan</s<span class="highlight_match">pan</span>> likes tinker <span class="highlight_match">bell</span>
```

It's caused because the function is iterating the list of terms to look for so the second+ iterations can have the <span class="highlight_match">..</span> text and if the search term for the current iteration matches anything in the given string (including any text/html that we just added in a previous iteration) it gets replaced.

I am not sure how to solve this issue.  Is there a function/way to do all the different matches/replacements on the string at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put all the strings into one pattern:

```php
$highlighted = preg_replace(
    "/(peter|pan)/i", 
    "<span class=\"highlight_match\">$1</span>",
    $text_to_search);
```

In this case, the pattern `(peter|pan)` means “*peter* or *pan*”.

There's another solution which is more flexible than the simple *OR* pattern. It works if you really need to apply your replacements one after another.

It works in two steps: First you replace the texts like you did before, but you don't insert the `<span>`s, but a placeholder which does never match your patterns. In the second step, you replace the placeholders with the actual highlighting tags:

```php
$replace = array('pan', 'bell');
$text_to_search = 'peter pan likes tinker bell';

$delim = 'yB9oMjDWpMy'; // just a random string; must not match your patterns
$tags = array(
    "open_$delim" => '<span class="highlight">',
    "close_$delim" => '</span>'
);

foreach ($replace as $term)
{
    $text_to_search = preg_replace(
        "/($term)/i",
        sprintf('open_%1$s$1close_%1$s' , $delim),
        $text_to_search);
}

// intermediate result:
// peter open_yB9oMjDWpMypanclose_yB9oMjDWpMy likes tinker open_yB9oMjDWpMybellclose_yB9oMjDWpMypeter pan likes tinker bell

$text_to_search = str_replace(
    array_keys($tags),
    array_values($tags),
    $text_to_search);

// final result
// peter <span class="highlight">pan</span> likes tinker <span class="highlight">bell</span>
```

This a bit more complicated, but it allows using a wider variety of regex patterns.

Comment: If you parenthesize the component regexps, there should be no problem with the first approach. Matches are always non-overlapping, so this seems the safer solution.